# What is the status of the redesign of the support forums?

Tags: discussion, promotion, wordpress.org

When the initial announcement of this site was made on the `wp-hackers` list, there were responses that [the team would focus on WordPress.org](http://lists.automattic.com/pipermail/wp-hackers/2010-June/032370.html) between the release of 3.0 and 3.1.

Has this happened? I could not find anything on the WP Devel forums for the [`forum`](http://wpdevel.wordpress.com/tag/forum/) or [`support`](http://wpdevel.wordpress.com/tag/support/) tags, but I don't know where I should follow these proposals? The [`wp-docs` archives](http://lists.automattic.com/pipermail/wp-docs/) seem to be quiet about this.

I'm of course asking this because it could be a final opportunity for us to step up and propose WordPress.org gives Stack Exchange a chance, similar to [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com). Now that we are nearing the end of our beta period, and even more users with a good reputation on regular WordPress channels join us, I think this could be a good time to learn from the initial reactions, demonstrate how this is different, and try to make a case for WPA.

Comment: *@Jan Fabry* - Good thought, but I fear those who run the WordPress community would rather have everything run on WordPress instead of relying on a 3rd party site. I'd *love* to be proven wrong, but I'm not hopeful...  Even though, this site is doing so much better job of surfacing great answers that I expect Google will eventually be all the promotion we need.

Comment: Ironically, there was a huge Twitter-fest yesterday regarding feature freeze for 3.1 and a somewhat rigorous testing/deployment cycle for 3.1.  The core team promises it out before Christmas ... considering the feature development and bug fixes required to meet that deadline, I don't see a whole lot of room for WP.org improvements before 3.1 ships ...

Answer (score 3):

I don't mean to sound pessimistic, but I honestly doubt you'll see overt promotion on wp.org.

That said, adding some "see also" links in the wiki and in the wp.org forum, pointing to answers in WP answers, is innocent looking enough and quite likely to steer a lot of traffic to the site.

Comment: Hi *@Denis*, *Really* glad to have your participation here.

Comment: Heh, I didn't say I'd actually post those links myself. ;-) It's been a very very long time since I've visited the WP forum or wiki myself. But that's basically how I launched my own website 5 years ago.

Comment: No, I just meant glad to have you participating *here* at WordPress Answers.  The site will promote itself over time as the site surfaces more and better answers and Google routes more people here.